# SELECT Cursor utilizando top1

Tags: sql, query, pl-sql

Necessito retornar somente o maior valor de uma das linhas abaixo, levando em consideração que preciso apresentar também o código do pedido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei rodar via cursor mas sem sucesso. Pelo cursor passaria as 3 linhas, mas precisaria considerar somente uma de maior valor.

Como resolvo isso? Alguma ajuda? Estou no caminho certo?

Comment: qual critério pretende usar para "cod_pedido", o maior ou menor? Já que os demais campos são igual, precisa ordenar de alguma forma. Deve retornar qual dos "cod_pedido"?

Comment: Não existe um critério,o importante é retornar o maior valor de um dos dois pedidos.   Podemos considerar último pedido, desde que ele tenha o maior valor.

Answer (score 0):

No SQL Server eu tentaria usar:

```
row_number()over(partition by COD_PEDIDO order by VALOR desc)as Ordem
```

Ele vai "agrupar" pelo `COD_PEDIDO` e ordenar os valores de cada cod.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia usar um `max(cod_pedido)` ou `min(cod_pedido)` para trazer apenas um valor.
Seria algo assim:

```
SELECT dt_pedido,
       cod_cli,
       max(cod_pedido) as cod_pedido,
       max(valor) as valor
FROM exemplo
GROUP BY dt_pedido,
         cod_cli
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcional aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c168c/1